# Why do some characters show as squares in Chrome?

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, character-encoding, chrome

For example in the dev tools I get something like:

[image: Chrome dev tools]

Some of these squares are at the end of lines, initially I thought they were carriage returns but it turns out they aren't.

Also, squares appear after `=` or `>` in many places where there is no newline, and looking at the file in a hex editor shows that there isn't any character at all between `=` and `"` (e.g. `id="` is showing as `id=? "`)

This also turns up very occasionally in web pages, for example I saw:

[image: Google search result]

I copied that sentence, looked at it in a hex editor, and again there is no character between `e` and `:`. Nothing shows up in the source code either.

I have never seen this before, and its only since I re-installed arch a few days ago.

Chrome is: Version `19.0.1084.15 dev`
Arch is: Kernel `3.3.1-1-ARCH`, `x86_64`

`locale.gen` has `en_GB` locales uncommented (both `UTF-8` and `ISO-8859-1`). The encoding in chrome defaults to `ISO-8859-1`, but switching it to `UTF-8` makes no difference.

This is the html file I was using: [test.html](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22257420/Dump/test2.html)

A fix would be fantastic, an explanation would be great, confirming that this is (or isn't) just a problem with my setup would also be good.

Edit: After investigating fonts, I found that in both cases it was trying to use arial, which in arch is part of the `ttf-ms-fonts` package. Installing that resulted in the font changing, but the squares remained (although a different shape). In both cases the font does not adhere to the default fonts for the system.

[image: Chrome dev tools - with arial]

Comment: It works and display fines for me. I guess it should be a problem with your setup, maybe your font rendering system.

Comment: @Coren, I forgot about fonts :P I'll take a look now.

Answer (score 29):

This fixed the problem for me. Install the dejavu fonts.

```
sudo pacman -S ttf-dejavu
```

Comment: Beautiful - this solved my problem also.

Comment: This messed up my terminal fonts and removal by pacman -R ttf-dejavu has lot of chained dependencies, pacman -Rdd ttf-dejavu doesn't solve the removal and resetting of fonts

Comment: Installing any other font that has the problematic characters would also work

Comment: still works in 2017

Comment: If you are getting squares with the flash plugin for Chromium, try this.

Comment: Still works in 2020.

Comment: Still works in 2021.

Answer (score 13):

There's a better way to determine what font you're missing instead of blindly installing font packages.

For example I did the following to resolve missing fonts:

1. I received an email with two unknown Unicode characters (codepoints: `U+1F44B`, `U+1F3FC`)
2. Paste them here: https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer#e=8J-Ri_Cfj7w
3. Review the results which will show you fonts that have those emojis/characters
4. Install only the needed font packages, for me `pacman -S noto-fonts-emoji` worked.
5. Rebuild font cache `fc-cache -vf`
6. Restart Chrome/Chromium

Alternatively you can lookup the Unicode name to aide in Google searches looking for fonts:

```
$ echo -e  | python -c 'import unicodedata, sys; s=sys.stdin.read().rstrip(); print([{ascii(c): unicodedata.name(c)} for c in s])'
[{"'\\U0001f44b'": 'WAVING HAND SIGN'}, {"'\\U0001f3fc'": 'EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-3'}]
```

You can also can let Python read from stdin. To do that run the script without `echo ... |`, copy-paste the unknown Unicode character, hit enter and CTRL-D to close `stdin`, and python will return the result.

Comment: For the Italian flag, which is made of the _Regional Indicator Symbol Letter I_ and _Regional Indicator Symbol Letter T_ Unicode characters, https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer#e=8J-Ri_Cfj7w was able to find only the latter character in the Noto Emoji font. I would have installed a different font, which had both the characters, when Noto Emoji had both the characters.

Comment: Found my missing font is noto-fonts-cjk from this answer, reboot and works!

Answer (score 8):

It's standard to print the [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) in place of a character which does not exist in the current font.

A possible fix is simply to change the default font of either your OS (if the browser inherits the OS settings) or the browser. For example, my Firefox 11.0  on Ubuntu 11.10 is using the "serif" font (which might be a synonym for [FreeSerif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_UCS_Outline_Fonts)), which seems to support a lot of Unicode characters.

PS: The images seem to have disappeared.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After the comment from coren I did some investigating, and found that the square from the google result (second image) was trying to use `arial`. I installed `ttf-ms-fonts` which resulted in a change: the squares are now a different shape. I will try and find what the default fonts are.

Comment: `which resulted in a change: the squares are now a different shape` I'm sorry that I laughed so hard at that.

Answer (score 8):

installing the `noto` font from google, did it for me.

```
yay -S noto-fonts
```

Now, reload the font cache:

```
fc-cache -vf
```

Comment: And also install emojis `yay -S noto-fonts-emojis`

Comment: Adding both the fonts worked for me, on Manjaro.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.  [This page](http://ralsina.me/stories/BBS52.html), for example, was particularly unreadable, with squares appearing all throughout the text of the page.  I was able to fix it by renaming all the `arial*.ttf` files in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts` to backup filenames and then setting Chrome's default sans-serif font to Droid Sans.  I can't use Arial fonts at all now, but at least the pages look right.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Using the past posts as a guide, I downloaded and installed the Font Changer Chrome extension.  Using FC to change to Arial fixed the problem.  Other fonts may also work, but I haven't tried them yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed all [Noto Fonts](https://github.com/notofonts/noto-fonts) packages. That should cover almost all Unicode characters that you could encounter on the internet.

```bash
sudo pacman -S noto-fonts noto-fonts-extra noto-fonts-cjk noto-fonts-emoji
# Note: It could take some time to download all the packages
```

Restart your browser / application / GUI / Desktop Environment / Computer / whatever to make it work. You could also do `fc-cache -vf` just in case.

To save space / bandwith / time, you can just install `noto-fonts`, the rest is optional, but increases coverage:

- `noto-fonts-extra` is for additional styles like condensed, semi-bold and extra-light.
- [`noto-fonts-cjk`](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-cjk) is for [Chinese, Japanese, and Korean languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters).
- [`noto-fonts-emoji`](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji) is for [Emojis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)).

#### More about Noto:

> Noto is a collection of high-quality fonts with multiple weights and widths in sans, serif, mono, and other styles. The Noto fonts are perfect for harmonious, aesthetic, and typographically correct global communication, in more than 1,000 languages and over 150 writing systems.
>
> [...]
>
> Noto includes fonts for nearly all of the world's writing systems
> (scripts): from Latin, Chinese, Arabic, Hebrew, and all Indic scripts,
> to Egyptian hieroglyphs and emoji.
>
> Source: https://fonts.google.com/noto

> Noto’s goal is to provide a beautiful reading experience for all languages. It is a free, professionally-designed, open-source collection of fonts with a harmonious look and feel in multiple weights and styles. All Noto fonts are published under the SIL Open Font License (OFL) v1.1, which allows you to copy, modify, and redistribute them if you need to.
>
> Source: https://github.com/notofonts/noto-fonts#noto-fonts

#### More context:

Many widely used [open source fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_Unicode_typefaces) (like [GNU Unifont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont#Status), [GNU FreeFont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_FreeFont#Unicode_coverage), [Open Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sans#Unicode_support) and [DejaVu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts#Unicode_coverage)) don't support characters of all languages, especially Asian. Though if you don't need Asian characters, DejaVu (package `ttf-dejavu`) is still a good choice.

The Arch Wiki also recommends Noto for displaying Asian characters:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fonts#Pan-CJK

After installing the Noto packages, applications that use a different font which doesn't support a certain character, should use a Noto as a fallback for those characters. That is, if you use [Fontconfig](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Font_configuration) on your system, which most Linux Distributions, including Arch, do:

> Fontconfig automatically chooses a font that matches the current
> requirement. That is to say, if one is looking at a window containing
> English and Chinese for example, it will switch to another font for
> the Chinese text if the default one does not support it.
>
> Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fonts#Fallback_font_order