# Mozilla won't show special characters (such as chinese, korean, japanese, etc...) just numbers in squares on Debian

Tags: debian, fonts, character-encoding

I just installed Debian 10.3 and when I try to read special characters i see what is shown on the picture below. What am I supposed to do?

I've read some solutions, but they were only for arch linux, I am not sure how to do it on Debian. Any suggestions?

[image: Mozilla won't display Korean characters]

Comment: Have you tried installing an appropriate font? The package `fonts-noto` should do the trick.

Comment: @Hermann you were right now i can see them, thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some characters show as squares in Chrome?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36291/why-do-some-characters-show-as-squares-in-chrome)

Comment: @PauloTomé not really because they use different packages, i wanted to know the name of the package actually for debian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your system has no font which includes the special or asian glyphs. The package `fonts-noto` should contain fonts for all eventualities.